# wp_insert_post(), creates two pages?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I want to create a new page in wordpress by using this. It is working  but it creates two pages. Can any one help me to fix this problem .

```
    $my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'profile',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_author'   => 1
  );enter code here
```

Insert the post into the database

```
wp_insert_post( $my_post, $wp_error );
```

I think this must create only one page.

Comment: are you sure this code is not inside any loop ?

Comment: As @prince alludes, the wp_insert_post line is getting run twice - it may be because of a loop, or because it's in a function called by an action hook (they sometimes get called more than once). Please post more code so that we can assist.

Comment: thanks .... But when I am trying to generate a 'post' using same code it is working.  
Although I have solved my problem by generating 'post' and then updating it as 'page' using my custom sql query.  
**Note** : On using 'wp_update_post()' it gave same error.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error before, when i am running a custom php script to insert posts into the Wordpress database, using the **wp_insert_post** statement. Weirdly it created 2 records in **wp_posts** table for every post.

Not sure what is the issue, but i realized that when i ran the php code in the same browser where i am logged in as administrator, i got this duplicate posts issue. I resolved it by running my custom php code in a separate browser.

So make sure that you are running your custom php code with SQL query in a browser, that has no Wordpress login in it. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. You saved my day. This issue is really weird. It even caused the code after wp_insert_post to execute twice in my case. Once I ran my import code in a browser window that I'm not logged in, every thing worked correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to create a custom Template page with a functionality to add a post,but by default the header and the footer has the loop for getting all the posts, and I think so that loop were creating two posts, because my page was not requiring the begin post loop, i just removed all of them and just had my own custom function to insert the post, it worked for me.